# How to make a closing a sliding div when you click outside of it?

Tags: jquery, click, slide, slidetoggle

Please help me! I create a simple sliding block and I'm trying to make it close when you click anywhere on the page, except for sliding "black" content.

See JSFiddle: [jsfiddle.net/2DaR6/233/](http://jsfiddle.net/2DaR6/233/)

Javascript

```
$(".black ").hide();
$(".white").show();
$('.white').click(function(){
    $(".black ").slideToggle(150);
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="black">
    content
</div>

<a href="#" class="white">click me!</a><br />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this perhaps http://jsfiddle.net/HE2Qg/

```
$(".black ").hide().click(function(){
    return false;
});
$(".white").show().click(function(){
    $(".black ").slideToggle(150);
    return false;
});
$(document).click(function(){
    $(".black ").slideUp(150);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

http://jsfiddle.net/7QNnJ/1/

```
$(".black ").hide();
$(".white").show();
$('.white').click(function(e){
    $(".black ").slideToggle(150);
    e.stopPropagation();
});

$(document).on('click', function(e){
    if( !$('.black').is(":hover")){
        $('.black').slideUp();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to change the click function:

```
$('.white').click(function(event) {
  $(".black ").slideToggle(150);
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

And add these two functions:

```
$(".black").click(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
});

$("html").click(function() {
  $(".black").slideToggle(150);
});
```

This will make it so that if you click anywhere on the page, the `html`'s click handler will try to close the `div`. However, if you are clicking on the `div` or the "click me" link, `event.stopPropagation()` will prevent the event from reaching the `html`'s click handler.

[Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2DaR6/252/)